# API call giving empty array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

This is 'product.js' file, and when ever I am calling the api '/achaar/products/1', the value of val is giving empty in console. Other api calls like '/achaar/products' is working fine, but on calling with id this is not working.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const json_data = require('./test_data');
const cons = require('./constants')

/*
url is : /achaar/products
replace test data with database datas
*/

router.get(cons.URLS.all_product,(req,res) => {
res.json(json_data)
})

router.get(cons.URLS.all_product+'/:id',(req,res) => {
console.log(req.params.id)
var val = json_data.achaar.filter(function (x) { return x.id === req.params.id })
console.log(val)
})

module.exports = router
```

Here is my test_data.js file

```
 {
 "achaar" : [
    {
        "id" : 0,
        "name" : "Ginger Tangi",
        "cost" : 2000
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Mango Khatta",
        "cost" : 1200
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Gaas Dhari",
        "cost" : 3000
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Cream Tangy",
        "cost" : 1000
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: `req.params.id` is a string, and you're checking using type/value equality on an _integer_ in your data. Try converting the id to a number: `Number(req.params.id)` and then doing the check.

Comment: [More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `===` and it was check value and type is equal

You should convert `req.params.id` to number because `id` of data is number.